# Joining three DB2 tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have to join three tables for my report.

Table1:

```
DTL_MTCH_KEY  TRAN_AM   SYS_IND    
  1234567       10        
  1234567       10
  1234567       10
  1234567       10
  2222222       25         Y
  2222222       25         Y
```

Table2:

```
DTL_MTCH_KEY    SUM_TRAN_AM     JR_NAME
   1234567          40          AAAAAAA
   2222222          50          BBBBBBB
```

Table3:

```
DTL_MTCH_KEY   SYS_IND    ERR_MSG 
   2222222        Y       ISSUE WITH PRODUCT
```

My output must be like below

```
DTL_MTCH_KEY  TRAN_AM   JR_NAME  ERR_MSG 
  1234567       10      AAAAAAA             
  1234567       10      AAAAAAA
  1234567       10      AAAAAAA
  1234567       10      AAAAAAA
  2222222       25      BBBBBBB  ISSUE WITH PRODUCT       
  2222222       25      BBBBBBB  ISSUE WITH PRODUCT
```

Requirement.

1. I want to join table1, 2 and 3.
2. List all the values from Table 1 and get the JR_NAME from table2.
3. Whenever Table1 SYS_IND is Y, then get the ERR_MSG from Table3.
4. I have to do this in single query.

I tried below and it bring up duplicate rows. I had 229002 rows in my TABLE1 but my query bring up 385717 rows.

```
Select A.DTL_MTCH_KEY, A.TRAN_AM, B.JR_NAME, C.ERR_MSG 
FROM TABLE1 A 
     LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B 
        ON (A.DTL_MTCH_KEY = B.DTL_MTCH_KEY) 
     LEFT JOIN TABLE3 C 
        ON (A.DTL_MTCH_KEY = C.DTL_MTCH_KEY 
            AND C.SYS_IND = 'Y') 
WHERE DATE = '2022-05-26'
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what exactly is your question.

Comment: I tried joining the tables with the left join and it pulled the same rows multiple times. As I posted here, I'm something other options as well.

Comment: Please, as requested before by Jonas, share/show what you have tried and what exactly is your question.  Please explain why the SQL you have created is failing in your case ?

Comment: I tried below and it bring up duplicate rows.
``````Select A.DTL_MTCH_KEY,
                A.TRAN_AM,
                B.JR_NAME,
                C.ERR_MSG
   FROM TABLE1   A
   LEFT  JOIN TABLE2  B  ON (A.DTL_MTCH_KEY = B.DTL_MTCH_KEY)
  LEFT  JOIN TABLE3 C  ON (A.DTL_MTCH_KEY = C.DTL_MTCH_KEY AND C.SYS_IND = 'Y')
WHERE DATE  = '2022-05-26'
`````````

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.DTL_MTCH_KEY,A.TRAN_AM,B.JR_NAME,C.ERR_MSG
FROM Table1 A 
INNER JOIN Table2 B on A.DTL_MTCH_KEY = B.DTL_MTCH_KEY
LEFT JOIN Table3 C on A.DTL_MTCH_KEY = C.DTL_MTCH_KEY AND A.SYS_IND = C.SYS_IND AND A.SYS_IND ='Y'
```

Comment: I tried with Inner and Left join. Its bringing duplicate row. I have 229002 records in the table and My join bringing up 385717 records.

Comment: i test it and it will work and the result is equal to you, first join must be INNER JOIN and Second one LEFT JOIN this is the result: \n 1234567 10 AAAAAAA NULL
1234567 10 AAAAAAA NULL
1234567 10 AAAAAAA NULL
1234567 10 AAAAAAA NULL
2222222 25 BBBBBBB ISSUE WITH PRODUCT
2222222 25 BBBBBBB ISSUE WITH PRODUCT

Comment: And if table3 have sys-in <> ‘y’ values you must filter for just ‘y’ in where condition

Comment: Sorry for late response. I did two left join and it worked as execpected.
``````
from TABLE1  A
 left join   TABLE2  B  on A.DTL_SUM_MTCH_KEY = B.DTL_SUM_MTCH_KEY
                                 and a.DB_CRD_ID = B.DB_CRD_ID
 left join TABLE3  C  on (A.SPNS_IND_YN = 'Y' AND A.DTL_SUM_MTCH_KEY = C.DTL_SUM_MTCH_KEY 
          AND A.FIN_TRAN_ROW_ID = C.FIN_TRAN_ROW_ID)
          
WHERE A.DATE > '2022-05-24'
````````

Answer (score -1):

try using the following queries
[image]

Comment: I tried this and got duplicate rows. Also I don't have to hit TABLE3 unless TABLE1 has Y in SYS_IND.

Comment: please post code, not pictures of code